# PHP PDO Username Availability Checker

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a registration page that uses JQuery's validator plugin to validate the form. For the username, i used the [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) method. So here's my jquery+html code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psYHk/4/)

And here's Available.php:

```
<?php 
    $usr = $_POST['username'];
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***;charset=UTF-8','***','***');
    $usr_check = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM Conference WHERE Username = :usr");
    $usr_check->bindParam(':usr', $usr);
    $usr_check->execute();
    if($usr_check->rowCount()>0)
        echo false;
    else
        echo true;
?>
```

So I have a test account in my database with the username: user. When I tried to submit my form with the same username, it didn't display the error saying "username taken" which means the php isn't correct. Any ideas where I went wrong? Thanks

Edit: Ran the website with chrome's inspector open. When the user name is entered it DOES try to get Available.php but it says "500 internal server error". Here's what it looks like:
[image: 500 Error]

Comment: Did it display anything or you got a JS error?

Comment: @LukaszKujawa no nothing like that. So my php is correct then?

Comment: I think the php is correct. I had a issue once with case sensitivity of the user name

Comment: @JohnBernal Where is it you call `val`?

Comment: @JohnBernal val? What do you mean?

Comment: @JvdBerg do you think it should be $_REQUEST instead of $_POST?

Comment: @JohnBernal In your jquery code, you set the value of the variable `val` to the validation function.

Comment: $_POST seems ok to me. How about the case of the username you are passing and the collate of the database? `John != john`

Comment: @Daedalus ah, here's the rest if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/psYHk/2/

Comment: @JvdBerg yah in the database the test username is user, and the one i type is user. Is that what you meant?

Comment: `$link->bindParam(':usr', $usr);` is likely wrong. you bind parameters to the statement, not the database connection. Take `$usr_check->bindParam(':usr', $usr);` instead. PHP should have given you a fatal error, do proper error checking.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages.

Comment: @hakra i changed it to user_check but the error message "username already taken" still doesn't display meaning that it is unable to find the inputted username (user) in the database (which it should)

Comment: Edit your question to reflect your current code. Also you need to debug your code. You only take the very end result, you need to find the place where your expectations are broken first time. E.g. are you sure and can you proof that the username is actually being checked for? Which username value is being used *inside* that function? That's called debugging. You find out something does not work and then you start to find out. There is not much we can do here (if the error is not obvious), because we can not run your code under the same conditions as you do (hard to reproduce) http://sscce.org/

Comment: @hakra updated. I normally always debug, but I have no idea how I would debug this. it's not like i can `var_dump` because this is a plugin making a remote request. How do I check to see what Available.php is getting?

Comment: do you use rowcount more than once in the same file ?

Comment: @JohnBernal: Either by outputting this and looking into the response with the developer tools of your browser (firebug, network panel, also in chrome SHIFT+CTRL+J) and then seeing the response. The other option is to log and to `$ tail -f logfile` in a console. Whatever suits you more.

Comment: @CastielMartin no i don't. Available.php is only a 11 line file.

Comment: @JohnBernal Well, it may be a problem with your server.  I have your current code working fine for me.

Comment: Well I get *"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in ..."* however that must not say much. Just an example what *could* happen.

Comment: @Daedalus what kind of problem would it be?

Comment: You sure your server has PDO configured with MySQL? Are you using it somewhere else?

Comment: @SimonGermain yah that's how i'm inserting the user's information into the database in the first place.

Comment: Can you check your web server's error log?

Comment: @SimonGermain just how do i do that exactly?

Comment: Could you please create a chatroom to troubleshoot the issue? I'd like to see this question deleted, because it does not look like that it is of use to anybody else next to the OP who needs to do interactive debugging here on SO because new to programming (which is no sin). Also you can read better in the chat then in comments here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after chatting with you for a while, here's what we found:

1- $_POST should be $_GET, since you're using a remote method from jQuery.validate.

2- Your code was calling bindParam() on $link instead of $usr_check, which is correct in your question.

Another thing, your code also needs to print out strings for true and false. Wrap those in quotes.