# PHP Retrieve Column In Lowercase

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO Username Availability Checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656617/php-pdo-username-availability-checker)

I have a php script that checks the availability of a username (if it's taken already or not). But I want to compare the username typed in by the user and the usernames in the database in lowercase. I already put the input in lowercase, but how do I make the retrieved column in lower case. Here's the php script

```
<?php 
    $usr = strtolower($_GET['username']);
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***;charset=UTF-8','***','***');
    $usr_check = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM Conference WHERE Username = :usr");
    $usr_check->bindParam(':usr', $usr);
    $usr_check->execute();
    if($usr_check->rowCount()>0)
        echo "false";
    else
            echo "true";
?>
```

How do i set the username column to lowercase, then compare it to `$usr`? Thanks

Comment: do you only need username in this mysql query?

Comment: What's really strange is [I've seen this exact question once before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656617/php-pdo-username-availability-checker#comment17075255_12656617).

Comment: @Charlie Yabben you can simply "SELECT 1 FROM Conference WHERE Username = :usr" without converting your column.

Comment: @CharlieYabben Did you forget your login?  Did you get banned on your old account?  Nothing else could explain why you have the exact same code as another user, even down to the database table.

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
 SELECT * FROM Conference WHERE LOWER(Username) = :usr
```

http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_upper_lower.php

ok as you said on the comment below I recommend you to do the following.

1. convert your result into lowercase http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd50e/1
2. convert your comparison string to the table into lowercase by using strtolower
3. now compare the results

Comment: can I do `SELECT LOWER(Username) FROM Conference WHERE Username = :usr`?

Comment: @CharlieYabben Yes, but SELECT Username FROM Conference WHERE LOWER(Username) = :usr. That's useless, it's case insensitive.

Comment: @Mahan The thing is, if `User` exists in the database, I don't want someone making an account with `user` as the username. So will both my code and urs achieve this means?

Comment: have a look on this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd50e/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
SELECT * FROM Conference WHERE LOWER(Username) = :usr
```

as the query, but that would cost you the benefit of an index.

However, the comparison should be case insensitive anyways if the column uses a "ci" collation.

Comment: BTW, in that case even if you convert string to LOWER(Username). It will still accept if the username is the same. That's case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string to lower in MySQL use LOWER(str) function.